# How makes all low values in the symbolic calculation become zero?

Tags: python, sympy

How can I make all low values in a SymPy expression zero? For example, my result is:

```
1.0*a1*cos(q1) - 6.12e-17*(a2*sin(q2) + a3*sin(q2 + q3) + a4*sin(q2 + q3 + q4))*sin(q1) + 1.0*(a2*cos(q2) + a3*cos(q2 + q3) + a4*cos(q2 + q3 + q4))*cos(q1)
```

and I want to change second term (starting with `6.12e-17`) to zero.

Comment: If you arrived at this expression by calling evalf then you can use chop=True when calling evalf: `(cos(2)**2+sin(2)**2-1.0).evalf(chop=True)`

Answer (score 2):

A direct way to do this is to replace such numbers with 0. A naive `eq.subs(small, 0)` will fail because `small` that you enter is not likely to be exactly the same as the number. But `eq.atoms(Float)` will give you the set of such numbers:

```
>>> eq.xreplace(dict([(n,0) for n in eq.atoms(Float) if abs(n) < 1e-12]))
1.0*a1*cos(q1) + (1.0*a2*cos(q2) + 1.0*a3*cos(q2 + q3) + 1.0*a4*cos(q2 + q3 + q4))*cos(q1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are much more efficient ways(I am not familiar with that library) but I tried to do with `regex`. If `e-` exist in a part of the equation it replaces it to 0(you can remove directly if you want). But to be able to do this, I had to remove to spaces between `+-` operators inside the parentheses, so I could make a list by splitting from the other `+-` operators.

```
import re
result='''1.0*a1*cos(q1) - 6.12e-17*(a2*sin(q2) + a3*sin(q2+q3) 
+ a4*sin(q2+q3+q4))sin(q1) + 1.0(a2*cos(q2) 
+ a3*cos(q2+q3) + a4*cos(q2+q3+q4))*cos(q1)'''
too_small='e-'

mylist=re.split(r"\s+", result)

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if too_small in mylist[i]:
        mylist[i]='0'

new_result=''.join(mylist)
print(new_result)
```

And this is the output:

```
1.0*a1*cos(q1)-0+a3*sin(q2+q3)+a4*sin(q2+q3+q4))sin(q1)+1.0(a2*cos(q2)+a3*cos(q2+q3)+a4*cos(q2+q3+q4))*cos(q1)
```

As I said, there are probably much better ways than this.

Answer (score 0):

What about more details? I guess you want replace part of a symbolic calculation string, Regular expression in Python could be helpful, you can code like this:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = '1.0*a1*cos(q1) - 6.12e-17*(a2*sin(q2) + a3*sin(q2 + q3) + ' \
   ...:     'a4*sin(q2 + q3 + q4))sin(q1) + 1.0(a2*cos(q2) + ' \
   ...:     'a3*cos(q2 + q3) + a4*cos(q2 + q3 + q4))*cos(q1)'

In [3]: s = re.sub(r'[+-/*/]\s\S*e-[1-9]\d+\S*\s', '', s)

In [4]: s
Out[4]: '1.0*a1*cos(q1) + a3*sin(q2 + q3) + a4*sin(q2 + q3 + q4))sin(q1) + 1.0(a2*cos(q2) + a3*cos(q2 + q3) + a4*cos(q2 + q3 + q4))*cos(q1)'
```

First argument of re.sub() function decide what you want to reduce, `e-[1-9]\d+` represent a number lower than e-10 which you can modify, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy’s `nsimplify` function with the `rational=True` argument converts floats within an expression to rational numbers (within a given tolerance). Something like `6.12e-17` will be converted to 0 if below the threshold. So, in your case:

```
from sympy import sin, cos, symbols, nsimplify

a1, a2, a3, a4 = symbols("a1, a2, a3, a4")
q1, q2, q3, q4 = symbols("q1, q2, q3, q4")

expr = (
      1.0*a1*cos(q1)
    - 6.12e-17*(a2*sin(q2) + a3*sin(q2 + q3) + a4*sin(q2 + q3 + q4))*sin(q1)
    + 1.0*(a2*cos(q2) + a3*cos(q2 + q3) + a4*cos(q2 + q3 + q4))*cos(q1)
    )

nsimplify(expr,tolerance=1e-10,rational=True)
# a1*cos(q1) + (a2*cos(q2) + a3*cos(q2 + q3) + a4*cos(q2 + q3 + q4))*cos(q1)
```