# How to set 0, higher than 0 in sympy after substituting

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have some lengthy expressions with symbols etc in them. After evaluating them while using .subs({...}) and substituting all variables,  I get values `10^{-18}` etc which I know they should be equal to zero.

Do you have some way to set them zero without checking every variable and doing it manually?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I can't to be honest. It uses GraviPy and the Expressions are lengthy and I really cant replicate a problem simplistically. Although the question is pretty straightforward no?

Comment: One problem is that sympy isn't very happy working with floats. It still tries to find exact symbolic solutions. Depending on the exact case, numerical methods (from scipy) could be helpful.

Comment: No, the problem isn't straightforward. Sympy works best with rational expressions. Other symbolic math systems often try to guess when using numerical methods and when to stay symbolic, but sympy concentrates on symbolic calculations.

Comment: Hi Billy, as someone else said, this is actually not a simple problem. (1) just post the expressions as they are, doesn't matter if they're big. Help others help you by showing exactly what is the problem you are working on. (2) Try substituting rational values into the expressions instead of floats, so that Sympy can apply exact arithmetic instead of approximate (as with floats).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How makes all low values in the symbolic calculation become zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57916749/how-makes-all-low-values-in-the-symbolic-calculation-become-zero)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yeah it does. I will delete the question tho as I found a minimalistic example finally and Now I can ask the correct question :)

Comment: @billy: If the existing question solved your problem, you need to do nothing (keep this question to help others finding their solution). If it doesn’t solve your problem, [edit] this question to clarify why. In no case, delete and re-ask your question – [edit] instead.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Really? Ok ok I let it as it is then. Ty for help!

Comment: @billy: By the (somewhat selfish) way: What you can do, is upvote the answers that helped you. I could almost not suggest that duplicate because it had no upvoted answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `chop` option for `evalf` (aka `n`):

```
>>> ((pi + pi*I)**2).n()
-0.e-21 + 19.7392088021787*I
>>> ((pi + pi*I)**2).n(chop=True)
19.7392088021787*I
```

You can set the level of chopping, too:

```
>>> ((pi + pi*I)**2).n(chop=1e-23)
-0.e-21 + 19.7392088021787*I
>>> ((pi + pi*I)**2).n(chop=1e-20)
 19.7392088021787*I
```